# Kotlin ArgumentMatcher error

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin, mockito

I have a problem that I have not found answer in google. I am writing Unit tests and I want to provide an argument matcher, so I can mock response from the function. I simply call:

```
Mockito.`when`(
    dataSource.sendPoke(Mockito.argThat({ argument -> true }))
).thenReturn(
    Observable.just(CommonResponse())
)
```

and all I receive is an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mockito.argThat({ argument -> true }) must not be null
```

I was using this approach in Java and everything was working fine. Can anyone tell me how to implement ArgumentMatcher in Kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok @Thomas Keller, `mokito-kotlin` helped me. The code that works for me is:

```
whenever(dataSource.sendPoke(any()))
    .thenReturn(Observable.just(CommonResponse()))
```

Thank you very much for the help :)

ps. if this is not the best solution feel free to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

`argThat` is meant to work for verification, not for stubbing. If you want to stub a specific answer based on your input, use `thenAnswer`, like this (in `mockito-kotlin` syntax):

```
val mock: DataSource = mock {
   on { sendPoke(any()) }.thenAnswer { Observable.just(it.arguments[0]) }
}
```

Mockito's plain Java syntax requires you to do

```
doAnswer { Observable.just(it.arguments[0]) }
    .`when`(dataSource.sendPoke(any()))
```

iirc.

Comment: What I want to achieve. I have a `sendPoke` function which takes an argument and I do not know what the argument will be. I need to tell Mockito that whatever argument will be then it should return the mocked result. In Java, I was doing it by `Mockito.argThat` but if it will not going to work in Kotlin then how can I resolve such problem?

Comment: The `thenAnswer` thing above is exactly what you need here. It allows you to return any mocked result based on a very specific argument (and it even allows you to use all or part of that argument in your result).